# Browser no longer minimizes after installing plist for IOS Enterprise app

Tags: ios, plist

I have a hyperlink with an href to:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/myFile.plist
```

And it installs correctly. Before IOS 8, the app downloaded and took you to the home screen on the device where you would watch the app icon indicate downloading. From there the user could easily launch the app as a next step.
This no longer happens...

Is there something that needs to be changed in the plist to trigger this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.myexample.com/download/iOS/myenterpriseapp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.swatchdog.enterprise</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0.34</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>subtitle</key>
                <string>myApp for iPad II and above</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>SwatchDog</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This desired behavior existed before IOS 8 but has since disappeared. This is an Enterprise application.